# Oreo runs STICKY service in background

Tags: android, service

According to the latest changes happened in Android version Oreo and above, Services are no more allowed to run in background. You will have to go for a foreground service if you want to execute the service when the App is not running. Does this also mean that START_STICKY will no more work?

I tried the below code

```
 public class MyService extends Service {
  private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               Log.d(TAG, "input : " + i);
               SystemClock.sleep(1000);
           }
       }
   }).start();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: returning START STICKY");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    super.onDestroy();
  }
 }
```

This is a simple service, which creates a thread inside and prints numbers.

I run this service (on a below Oreo device) and as soon as the service starts printing the numbers, I quit the App. Now, I can see the service is restarted after couple of seconds , which is expected.

Now I run the same code in an Oreo device. But there also, after force quitting the App, the service gets restarted just like the below Oreo devices. So, does it mean that START_STICKY will restart the service and still it will be executing silently even in Orero?  The restriction is only for starting a new Service from background?

Answer (score 0):

If your app was in foreground it is temporarily on whitelist and can start services unconfined.

It's not specified how long it lasts, but when your app is put in background it will be removed from that whitelist and no longer be able to start non-foreground services.

Comment: I force quit the App and after couple of seconds, I observed that the service is restarted. Since I force quit the App, does it mean it is white listed?

Comment: @user3339689 whitelist is managed internally by system, killing the app does not affect it. You should have several minutes before your app is removed from whitelist and considered idle.